# nixos - Installing citrix-receiver and all needed certs as part of `nixos-rebuild`

Tags: nixos

I've managed to install citrix receiver and configure it manually with the certs I need to log into my work computers, but I want to have this be part of my automatic provisioning that happens with `nixos-rebuild`

The steps to install and configure were as such:

- Install Citrix Receiver

`$ nix-env -i --arg config '{ allowUnfree = true;}' citrix-receiver`

- as root remount /nix/store in rw

`# mount -o remount,rw /nix/store`

- Go to the location of the icaclient keystore

`# cd home/dw/.nix-profile/opt/citrix-icaclient/keystore`

- Remove the cacerts directory that it defaults to and recreate cacerts as a symlink to /etc/ssl/certs

`# rm -rf cacerts && ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts`

- Go to cacerts and get Symantec certificates and unzip

`# cd cacerts && wget http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/roots.zip && unzip roots.zip`

- Look recursively for pem files after unzip and copy them into current directory

`find . -name "*.pem" -type f -exec cp {} . \;`

This all worked, but I have yet to find a good way to do this as part of regular provisioning.

Any nixos people that know the best way to do this?

Comment: Ideally what you'd do is override the `citrix-receiver` package so that it uses a custom `cacert` package containing your certificates. The `citrix-receiver` package takes `cacert` as a parameter. But first you'd have to produce a `cacert` deviration which matches what `citrix-receiver` expects; Which is a derivation which produces `/nix/store/abc123-symantec-cacert/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. `citrix-receiver` reads that bundle and produces the PEM files. Take a look at `/etc/static/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` to get a sense of how to produce the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild the citrix-receiver package with your own bundle:

The following code is untested. It could be put into `environment.systemPackages` in configuration.nix.

```
(citrix-reveiver.override {
  cacert = stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "symantic-cacerts";
    src = null;
    unpackPhase = ":";
    installPhase = ''
      ${pkgs.unzip}/bin/unzip ${./roots.zip}
      mkdir $out/etc/ssl/certs/
      find . -name "*.pem" -type f | xargs cat > $out/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    '';
  };
})
```

Comment: currently in `environment.systemPackages` I have this: http://nixpaste.lbr.uno/PvPw5gVc?nix. How do I add your solution into my existing config?